# Can we write down the explicit form of the decomposition field of cyclomotic field?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

If we have cyclomotic field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ and a prime number $p\nmid n$. Suppose the order of $p (\textrm{mod }n)$ is $f$. I guess that the decomposition field is $\mathbb{Q}(\bigcup_{(k,n)=1}\sigma_k(\alpha))$, where $\alpha=\zeta_n+\zeta_n^p+\zeta_n^{p^2}+\cdots+\zeta_n^{p^{f-1}}$ and $\sigma_k\in\textrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\mathbb{Q})$ sending $\zeta_n$ to $\zeta_n^k$.

I haven't found complete answer to the question. The related materials on books are low-dimensional examples. I hope someone can tell me the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of your background in ANT, but Galois theory applied to the decomposition of primes in a normal extension of number fields (such as in chapter 3 of Marcus' book "Number Fields") gives the answer. I reprove this directly. Since $p$ does not divide $n$, $p$ is unramified in $\mathbf Q(\zeta_n)$  (by direct computation of the discriminant), so that $\phi (n) = rf$, where $r$ is the number of prime ideals above $p$ and $f$ is the inertia of $p$ (the ramification index $e$ is $1$). Introduce the *Frobenius automorphism* $\sigma_p$ of $\mathbf Q(\zeta_n)$ defined by raising $\zeta_n$ to the $p$-th power and compute its order. Because $p$ is unramified, it is easily seen that for any $a\in A$ (=the the ring of integers of $\mathbf Q(\zeta_n)$), $\sigma_p (a)\equiv a^p$ mod $pA$ , which means that $\sigma_p$ actually induces the usual Frobenius automorphism extension of finite fields $(A/pA)/\mathbf F_p$$A$ 
ring of integers of $\mathbf Q(\zeta_n)$. Hence the order of $\sigma_p$ is $f$, and its fixed field $D$ has degree $r$ over $\mathbf Q$. This means that $D$ is actually the decomposition field of $p$ .

*Addendum*  Let us show that the decomposition field $D$ can be generated as suggested by the OP. For simplicity, write $\zeta =\zeta_n, L = \mathbf Q(\zeta), G = Gal (L/\mathbf Q)$. The element $\alpha = \zeta + \sigma_p (\zeta) + ... + \sigma_p^{f-1} (\zeta)$ is the trace of $\zeta $ in $L/D$, hence belongs to $D$. Similarly , the conjugates $\sigma_k (\zeta)$, with $(k,n)=1$, have traces $ \sigma_k (\alpha)$ because $G$ is commutative. For any finite extension $L/K$, it is known (and easily shown) that the trace map $L \to K$ is $K$-linear, and is surjective if $L/K$ is normal. This shows, since the $\sigma_k (\zeta)$ generate $L$ as a vector space over $\mathbf Q$, that the $ \sigma_k (\alpha)$ generate $D$ over $\mathbf Q$. Note that this argument is almost purely linear algebra.

Comment: Thanks a lot! As you said, the field $D$ which is fixed by $\sigma_p$ is the decomposition field. Then I want to know whether we could write down a finite set of generators of this field over $\mathbb{Q}$. I guess it will be of the form mentioned in the original question.

Comment: I think that you take the problem by the wrong end. To describe subextensions of a field extension L/K by giving sets of generators (which , at that, have no reason to be unique) is not a natural task. Galois theory was invented to do the job in a much more functorial way by playing with subgroups Gal(L/K) in the case of a galois extension. This doesn't mean that you can't compute explicit generators in particular cases, such as here. See my edit.

Comment: Thank you very much! I get it! I never noticed that the trace map $\frac{1}{[L:K]}\textrm{Tr}_{L/K}:L\to K$ is a rectraction of the embedding $K\to L$, whose $\mathbb{Q}$-linearity sends $\mathbb{Q}$-generators in $L$ to that in $K$. This remains true when the extensions $L/K/F$ are separable, I don't think normality is necessary for surjectivity. And the final conclusion is $D=\mathbb{Q}(\bigcup_{k=1}^n \sigma_k(\alpha))$.